# Word Stress in a 3 syllable phrase

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

the phrase "Never mind" is three syllable [nɛv ər maɪnd]. The first and the last syllable gets stressed. Am I right? [2nɛv ər 1maɪnd]. I think that "mind" gets the most stress. I would like to know your opinions. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's right, and that's what the **Sound Pattern of English** stress theory predicts.  The second syllable is unstressed, so it doesn't matter to the pattern in phrases, which has only to do with the primary stresses of the words that make up the phrases.  There are always alternative intonations used for special contrast or other purposes, and here, "1Never 2mind" also seems possible, to express disdain or exasperation.